# django safe or escape on img alt attribute

Tags: django, escaping, django-templates

Should i use `safe` or `escape` on `alt`?
Example:

```
<img src="{{ post.img }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
```

And what is difference between them? (example if possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use escape and safe in Django's template system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system)

Comment: i saw this, but i need to alt, so i am confused :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `escape` and be careful with chaining.

**Example:**

```
{{ post.title|escape }}
```

Per, [Django 3.1 documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/):
If you are chaining filters, a filter applied after safe can make the contents unsafe again. For example, the following code prints the variable as is, unescaped:

```
{{ var|safe|escape }}
```

### escape

Escapes a string’s HTML. Specifically, it makes these replacements:

### safe

Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.