# django http response html directly

Tags: django, http, response

I don't know why I'm getting directly the HTML content with tags.. . Rest of the code is ok, but content no.

```
def ShowContent(content):
    plantilla = get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({"content": content})
    renderizado = plantilla.render(c)
    return renderizado


def ShowNextTen(request):
    NextActQuery = Actividad.objects.all().order_by('fecha')
    NextAct = "Listado actividades<br>"
    for Act in range(0,10):
            NextAct += '<div class="activity">'
            NextAct += '<strong>' + NextActQuery[Act].titulo + '</strong><br>'
            NextAct += NextActQuery[Act].tipo_evento + "<br>"
            NextAct += NextActQuery[Act].fecha.strftime("%d-%m-%y") + "<br>"
            NextAct += '</div>'
    return HttpResponse(ShowContent(NextAct))
```

Comment: Why are you building up the HTML in your view in the first place? All that logic should be in the template.

Comment: Plus, by individually accessing the elements in the query, you're making 10 individual calls to the database rather than a single one.

Comment: Note that even if there is a valid answer already, what you are trying to do is considered a bad practice...html code goes in html files. If you need to render something, send the values in your context and do it in your template. 
Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response ...that does what you are doing with ShowContent

Comment: mh, I understand. I think its too late for chaning everything? :/

Answer (score 0):

In your template, use:

```
{{ content|safe }}
```

[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system)

Answer (score 0):

Your NextVar contents should be in a template, and in your case, it would probably be index.html, and it should extend a general template that contains what your current index.html contains. Writing plain html in python is not the way django was designed for, so not the optimal way.

Then, I would just use a ListView (with a Paginator if you want to be able to show the next 10 entries). Chances are that you wouldn't even have to add a line to your views.py.

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
...
url(r'^actividades/$', ListView.as_view(
    template_name="index.html",
    queryset=Actividad.objects.all().order_by('fecha')[:10],
    context_object_name="actividades")
)),
...
```