# React table with django namedtuple returns .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I want to make a table of with django `namedtuple` but getting an error. Headers(which is list) works fine though.

`views.py`:

```
info = [Info(id=5, location_id=861, f=None),Info(id=3, location_id=650, f=None)]
return render('index.html', {'info': info})
```

`index.html`

```
var headers = ['id', 'location', 'f']

var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <table className="table-hover">
                {this.props.headers.map(function(name, index) {
                    return <th key={ index }>{name}</th>;
                })};
                {this.props.tableContent.map(function(row, index) {
                    <tr key={index}>
                        return(
                            {row.map(function(col, i) {
                                <td key={i}>{col}</td>
                            })}
                        );
                    </tr>
                })};
            </table>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Table headers={headers} tableContent={info}/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I can't see any output and the console says: `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.tableContent.map is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put `safe` when receiving the data. To someone who might encounter this problem too. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system) question too