# Filter safe does not work on the shy tag issue

Tags: python, django, templates, frontend, css-hyphens

I have a problem with breaking words in the right place at the Django template. Appears `&shy;`
I'm trying to filter safe, but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="my_class">
        <h3>{{ object.title|safe }}</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc here:[safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

> safe
>
> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

And Django's templating engine does escaping automatically, look [When should I use escape and safe in Django's template system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system)