# What is the use of "| safe" when passing variables from Django to React.js?

Tags: javascript, django

So from a few articles and few examples I've seen, when passing a variable context to javascript, one would use something like:

```js
const variable_name = {{ variable | safe }}
```

I have tried to google but don't seem to find any answer. What is the use of "safe" here? And when do we use it? If you have any reference or articles I could refer to, that would be extremely helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use escape and safe in Django's template system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system)

Comment: This structure is called a "template tag" and/or "filter" for future searching. https://www.djangotemplatetagsandfilters.com/filters/safe/

Comment: **Warning**: Rendering into JavaScript like that from Django is **vulnerable to XSS attacks**, see [django-antipatterns - Rendering into JavaScript](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/rendering-into-javascript.html) to see why and the proper way to pass data to JavaScript. Disclaimer: I am the author of that antipattern (with another SO user being the owner of the site).

Comment: Important thing to remember is that you're not passing something from one system to another, with django you basically 'building a javascript file from scratch' before sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter safe indicates that the variable does not require escaping.

By default, django will escape all 'potentially unsafe' characters, such as HTML tokens for example, when rendering a variable into an HTML.

For example, if you have variable `var1 = "<b>Hello</b>"` then writing this:

```
 {{ var1 | safe }}
```

Renders to this HTML:

```
 <b>Hello</b>
```

While this:

```
 {{ var1 }}
```

Renders to this:

```
 %3Cb%3EHello%3C%2Fb%3E
```

So in the final result, in the first case you will see the world **Hello** in bold, while in the second example you will see just the string `<b>Hello</b>`.

The escaping is done by default primarily to prevent the XSS attack where the attacker can execute malicious code by passing, for example, a `<script>` token inside an input to a website.

So as a rule of thumb, you can use the 'safe' filter when you know for sure your string has no unsafe tags, for example if you generated this variable without basing it on any user input.

For more info, you can see the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe

Also you can read about XSS attacks, there is really a lot of info on this, just google.